# dispatchKeyEvent not called

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard

I have the following double tap gesture within a View extension as shown below. This event changes focus to my view below when fired. MyView.this.requestFocus(); is called, and the keyboard appears. Unfortunately (on a samsung galaxy note 2 running android 4.0.4) I do not receive the dispatchKeyEvent callback at all. On a Nexus 4 running android 4.4+ I receive this callback. I'm unsure of how to proceed.

```
    private class DoubleTapGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private Context mContext;
        private Rect mTextBounds;

        public DoubleTapGestureListener(Context context) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            float xValue = e.getX();
            float yValue = e.getY();

            for (PaintBrush brush : brushes) {
                mTextBounds = brush.getTextBounds();

                if (mTextBounds.contains((int)xValue, (int)yValue)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Doubletap on text!");
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    MyView.this.requestFocus();
                    imm.showSoftInput(MyView.this,
                            InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                }

            }

            return true;
        }

        public void setTextBounds(Rect mTextBounds) {
            this.mTextBounds = mTextBounds;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Soft keyboards don't send key events-  only physical keys and keyboards do.  Soft keyboards use the InputConnection to send events (which may be key events or may be commitText calls).  If you want to get all the events, you need to implement an InputConnection.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new to android development, but the events do fire off on other devices. So in this case what would be recommended so I may receive the fired events on the Galaxy note 2 as well as the nexus devices?

Comment: I specifically need a fire off event when they keyboard keys are pressed so I can append the string value to a model object I have and redraw the screen.

Comment: Android softKeyboards just don't work like that.  You'll have to implement an InputConnection for your view, which is a fair amount of work.